# Delete Row From Html Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an html table with delete button to remove unwanted row.
But when I click on delete button all previous added rows which has the same "id" will be not stored to the database. That means I can see previous rows in the table but after submit it will not saved to db. here is my code.

```
        $("table").on("click", ".removeproduct", function() {
            var el = this;
            var tr_pid = $(this).attr('tpid');
            var pid = $(this).attr('pid');
            var por_price = $(this).attr('por_price');
            var tax = $('#taxeshowrate').text();
            $('#add_product').prop("disabled", false);
            total = parseInt(total - por_price);
            maintotal = parseInt(maintotal - por_price);

            if (!tax) {
                tax = 0;
            }
            if (maintotal == tax) {
                maintotal = 0;
                $('#taxeshow').hide();
            }
            $('#pr_total').text(total);
            $('#total_amount_tax_with_show').text(maintotal);

            $(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
            $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            var newarray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < productarray.length; i++) {
                if (productarray[i].id != pid) {
                    newarray.push(productarray[i])
                }
            }
            productarray = newarray;
            console.log(productarray);
        })
```

Comment: if you have multiple rows with the same id you have a failure by design. id's must always be unique in a html dom

Comment: Also note that adding your own non-standard attributes to an element (such as `pid` and `tpid` in this case) is not good practice and can lead to unexpected issues. If you want to store custom metadata in an element use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.

Comment: The ID is for the product, not for raw.

Answer (score -1):

i can give you the list of errors not how to fix -

Main.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
$("table").on("click", ".removeproduct", function() {
^
Main.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
var tr_pid = $(this).attr('tpid');
^
Main.java:3: error: unclosed character literal
var tr_pid = $(this).attr('tpid');
^
Main.java:3: error: unclosed character literal
var tr_pid = $(this).attr('tpid');
^
Main.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
var pid = $(this).attr('pid');
^
Main.java:4: error: unclosed character literal
var pid = $(this).attr('pid');
^
Main.java:4: error: unclosed character literal
var pid = $(this).attr('pid');
^
Main.java:5: error: class, interface, or enum expected
var por_price = $(this).attr('por_price');
^
Main.java:5: error: unclosed character literal
var por_price = $(this).attr('por_price');
^
Main.java:5: error: unclosed character literal
var por_price = $(this).attr('por_price');
^
Main.java:6: error: class, interface, or enum expected
var tax = $('#taxeshowrate').text();
^
Main.java:6: error: unclosed character literal
var tax = $('#taxeshowrate').text();
^
Main.java:6: error: unclosed character literal
var tax = $('#taxeshowrate').text();
^
Main.java:7: error: class, interface, or enum expected
$('#add_product').prop("disabled", false);
^
Main.java:7: error: unclosed character literal
$('#add_product').prop("disabled", false);
^
Main.java:7: error: unclosed character literal
$('#add_product').prop("disabled", false);
^
Main.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
total = parseInt(total - por_price);
^
Main.java:9: error: class, interface, or enum expected
maintotal = parseInt(maintotal - por_price);
^
Main.java:11: error: class, interface, or enum expected
if (!tax) {
^
Main.java:13: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
Main.java:16: error: class, interface, or enum expected
$('#taxeshow').hide();
^
Main.java:16: error: unclosed character literal
$('#taxeshow').hide();
^
Main.java:16: error: unclosed character literal
$('#taxeshow').hide();
^
Main.java:17: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
Main.java:18: error: unclosed character literal
$('#pr_total').text(total);
^
Main.java:18: error: unclosed character literal
$('#pr_total').text(total);
^
Main.java:19: error: class, interface, or enum expected
$('#total_amount_tax_with_show').text(maintotal);
^
Main.java:19: error: unclosed character literal
$('#total_amount_tax_with_show').text(maintotal);
^
Main.java:19: error: unclosed character literal
$('#total_amount_tax_with_show').text(maintotal);
^
Main.java:21: error: class, interface, or enum expected
$(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
^
Main.java:21: error: unclosed character literal
$(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
^
Main.java:21: error: unclosed character literal
$(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
^
Main.java:21: error: unclosed character literal
$(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
^
Main.java:21: error: unclosed character literal
$(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
^
Main.java:21: error: unclosed character literal
$(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
^
Main.java:21: error: unclosed character literal
$(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
^
Main.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected
$(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function() {
^
Main.java:22: error: unclosed character literal
$(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function() {
^
Main.java:22: error: unclosed character literal
$(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function() {
^
Main.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
});
^
Main.java:25: error: class, interface, or enum expected
var newarray = [];
^
Main.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
for (var i = 0; i < productarray.length; i++) {
^
Main.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
for (var i = 0; i < productarray.length; i++) {
^
Main.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
for (var i = 0; i < productarray.length; i++) {
^
Main.java:32: error: class, interface, or enum expected
console.log(productarray);
^
Main.java:33: error: class, interface, or enum expected
})
^
46 errors

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).